# check if json dictionary has empty strings as a value

Tags: angularjs, string

what i am trying to achieve is to show and element only if an element's value within a JSON object is **NOT** equal to an empty string `''`.

#### For Example:

say i have the following json object

```
{
    'id' : 23,
    'name' : 'Adrian Reese',
    'age' : '',
    'location' : ''
}
```

now with in a partial template where i show the user information i do something like:

```
<h1>{{ user.name | capitalize }}</h1>
<span class="age">Age: {{ user.age }}</span>
<span class="location">Location: {{ user.location }}</span>
```

For each user i want the `<span>'s` to only be visible if the value is not equal to `''`. How can i achieve that ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `ngShow`: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngShow

```
<span ng-show="user.age != ''" class="age">Age: {{ user.age }}</span>
<span ng-show="user.location != ''" class="location">Location: {{ user.location }}</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your markup e.g. by `div` element with `ng-show`:

```
<div ng-show="user.age != ''">
    <h1>{{ user.name | capitalize }}</h1>
    <span class="age">Age: {{ user.age }}</span>
    <span class="location">Location: {{ user.location }}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a filter to specify the visible properties rules in code:

http://jsfiddle.net/g/sANcQ/2/

```
 <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
   <h1>{{ user.name }}</h1>
   <span ng-repeat="(key, value) in user | userVisibleProps" class="{{key}}">{{key}}: {{value}}</span>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.user = {
        'id' : 23,
        'name' : 'Adrian Reese',
        'age' : '',
        'location' : ''
    };
}

angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Ctrl', Ctrl)
  .filter('userVisibleProps', function(){
      return function(user) {
          var visibleUser = {};
          for(var key in user) {
              if(key != 'id' && user[key] !== '') {
                  visibleUser[key] = user[key];
              }
          }
          return visibleUser;
      };
  });

angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
```